# Deleted Loopback Model Property Still There

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have this object called 'ctx.instance' which has the following properties:

```
firstName: 'Ron',
lastName: 'Santo',
minor: true,
accepted: false,
emailChanged: false,
organizationId: 000000000000000001000001,
isDeleted: false,
userId: 55e17a46e410f9603cea515b
```

This object was passed into my function.  I need to strip off the 'emailChanged' property before saving it to the database.  So I did this:

```
delete ctx.instance.emailChanged;
```

The delete returns 'true' which means the property doesn't exist.

The following statement after the delete yields false which also means it should be gone:

```
'emailChanged' in ctx.instance
```

Yet, if I do a console.log(ctx.instance), the 'emailChanged' property is still there and it gets saved to the database.

If I check the property's properties, it says it is configurable.  If I do a console.log(ctx.instance.emailChanged) after the delete statement, it says 'undefined'.

Why is it still there?

I've searched all over the internet, tried tons of different things, and I can't find why this is occurring.  This is happening within a Node environment.

**UPDATE:**
The DB is Mongo.  I'm using Loopback.js models and framework.

The data variable is the object submitted to the server from the client via a PUT.  The data object was originally JSON but Loopback has made it a JavaScript object.

The code is within an operation hook so the save to the DB doesn't live within this function.

The 'delete' statement is the last statement within the function before I pass it back off to the framework.

Here is the minimum code for the hook:

```
  module.exports = function( Member )
  {
    Member.observe( 'before save', upsertMember );

    function upsertMember( ctx, next )
    {
      // displays 'true' 
      console.log( ctx.instance.hasOwnProperty( 'emailChanged' ) );

      // displays 'false'
      console.log( ctx.instance.emailChanged );
      var isDeleted = delete ctx.instance.emailChanged;

      // displays 'true'
      console.log( isDeleted );

      // displays 'false'
      console.log( 'emailChanged' in ctx.instance );

      // displays 'false' 
      console.log( ctx.instance.hasOwnProperty( 'emailChanged' ) );

      // displays 'undefined'
      console.log( ctx.instance.emailChanged );
      // displays object properties including 'emailChanged'
      console.log( ctx.instance );
      // pass control back to loopback for upsert
      // 'emailChanged' gets into MongoDB record
      next();
    }
  }
```

If any of you know a JSFiddle type of environment that includes Loopback, I'll throw it in there.

Screenshot of my debugger watch right after the delete statement:
[image]

Comment: will you also post some code please? How can we help to debug something without actually seeing it? :)

Comment: Can we have the code surrounding your `delete` statement and the sending to the DB, please ?

Comment: most likely it's not the same object

Comment: @StefanBaiu: Yeah, or that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The delete is occurring before the save to the database.  It is the last line in my hook before control gets passed back to the Loopback framework where the save occurs.  Also, I can put a console.log(data) right after the delete statement and the 'emailChanged' property is still there.

Comment: @ELMOJO: Did Mahesh's guess work, then? He guessed correctly that you were using MongoDb, does his solution solve the problem?

Comment: *(Revising earlier comment)* What you've described isn't possible for a normal JavaScript object. It would be possible for a host-provided object (since they don't have to follow JavaScript rules.) We'll need to see an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to help you with what's actually happening.

Comment: @ELMOJO: I think what everyone wants is some code snippets. Show us what's going on in the function where the `delete` happens. After you "pass it back off to the framework", what happens? Did you try to set a breakpoint and step into that function?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, Mahesh's answer did not work.  It did exactly as you said, it added the property onto the object.  So that the 'emailChanged' in data statement yields a true again.

Comment: @ELMOJO: what is the prototype of `ctx.instance`?

Comment: @StefanBaiu I haven't stepped into the framework because the 'emailChanged' property is still on the object when I do a console.log of the object after the delete.

Comment: In the code you just posted, you have the comment `displays object properties including 'emailChanged'` -- what **value** does it show for it?!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it shows false

Comment: @StefanBaiu: I was thinking prototype as well, but he said that `'emailChanged' in data` gave him `false`. `in` checks prototypes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  yeah I know, I was just curious what type of object is it

Comment: @ELMOJO: I'm sorry, I'm really having trouble believing that `console.log( ctx.instance.emailChanged );` displays `undefined` and then `console.log( ctx.instance );` shows an object with `emailChanged` having the value `false`. That has **got** to be observation error. In any case, there's no need for stumbling about in the dark with a `console.log` torch; use the debugger and turn on the lights.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder See newly added screenshot of the debugger watch window.

Comment: @ELMOJO: wait? what is `__data`? does `ctx.instance.hasOwnProperty('emailChanged')` before delete ?

Comment: @StefanBaiu ctx.instance.hasOwnProperty('emailChanged') yields 'true' before the delete.

Comment: @ELMOJO: That screenshot does not show what you described. It shows `ctx.instance` having `ctx.instance.emailChanged` property (**yes**, with the dots in the property name) with the value `undefined`, and **separately** having a `__data` property with `emailChanged` with the value `false`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, but ctx.instance.emailChanged shows 'false' in the watch window right before the delete.

Comment: I'm afraid SO's format is not a good fit for this question. You need someone to help you debug it, which we can't do in comments like this. That object is very strange. In particular, it's very strange that it has a property with the name `ctx.instance.emailChanged` actually **in** the object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I do appreciate all the help from everybody.  I should have RTFM.  According to Loopback, to remove an unwanted property do ctx.instance.unsetAttribute('unwantedField');

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Loopback Operation Hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks)

Removing unneeded properties

To remove unwanted properties (fields) from the context object, use the following:

```
ctx.instance.unsetAttribute('unwantedField');
```

This completely removes the field and prevents inserting spurious data into the database.

Should have done this:

```
ctx.instance.unsetAttribute('emailChanged');
```

Comment: Could you elaborate?  This is over a year old and I'm sure that Loopback has probably gone through a couple of minor versions since then.  What version are you using?  What are you trying to do?  Open a new thread and link it here in the comments and maybe we can figure it out.

Comment: well there are already a lot of threads that state this issue.Im using loopback 2.22, I tried debugging the server and using 

ctx.instance.unsetAttribute('unwantedField'); 

also tried  

delete ctx.data.unwantedfield;

and when I evaluate ctx.data.unwantedfield it's still there.

I should elaborate that this happens only for "bytea" datatype - Equivalent strongloop field is Binary.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be due to the PUT verb which is used to replace the whole instance and not only some attributes ?(To change only certain attributes you should use the PATCH verb).

So it might be loopback filling the missing attribute in the model and providing a default boolean value (false) for the "emailChanged" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the unnecessary property from being saved to dataabse using follwing statement Loopback version 3.

In case of `ctx.data`

```
delete ctx.data['propertyToBeRemoved'];
```

In case of `ctx.instance`

```
ctx.instance.unsetAttribute('propertyToBeRemoved')
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this works

```
data.emailChanged = undefined;
data.save(callback);
```

The questioner wants to delete the property of a model and save it to database. But the property of a model cannot be deleted using `delete`.

Comment: Read the question: *"The following statement after the delete yields false...`'emailChanged' in data`"* So the property does **not** exist in the object (or its prototypes). All the above does is create a property with the value `undefined`. But if the OP's code is behaving as described, that's not necessary or useful. The question cannot currently be answered, because it currently describes something that will not happen.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Can't you guess the problem? It is not a JavaScript Object. `gets save to the database`, `userId: 55e17a46e410f9603cea515b` thats clearly related to database model. `undefined` removes(unsets) the property in mongodb(from v2.4)